# Loop over binary Float64Array file - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv, stream, buffer

I have 100 CSV files, each about 50.000.000 rows and each containing 3 cells.

Each row needs to trigger an event to do some calculations. 
With the npm read-line lib, that reads the CSV though a pipe, I could get about 1.000.000 cycles of that process per second (1 node thread).

But this process does a lot of steps, just to get some numbers

1. Open .csv file stream
2. Stringify each chunk
3. Search for new line \n in chunk
4. Split that line into an array (3 cells)
5. parseFloat every cell

So to parse them even faster, I though converting the csv file to a binary file could help. So I created a binary Float64Array buffer file, as all values in the cells are floating numbers.

```
let counter = 0 ;;
rows.forEach(function (row) {

   row.forEach(function(cell) {

      buffer.writeDoubleLE(cell, counter++ * Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
   })
});
writeStream.write(buffer)
writeStream.end()
```

Then it only has to do this steps

1. Open .bin file stream
2. Convert every stream buffer chunk (chunk = 3 cells) to ArrayBuffer to Array64Float

   ```
   fs.createReadStream(fileName, {highWaterMark: 24})
       //.pause()
       .on('data', chunk => {
           //this._stream.pause();

           this._bufferOffset = 0;

           this.emit('tick', new Float64Array(chunk.buffer, chunk.byteOffset, chunk.byteLength / Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT));
       })
       .on('close', () => {
           let nextFile = this._getNextBINFilePath();

           if (!nextFile) {
               return this.emit('end');
           }

           this._initTestStream();
       })
   ```

All good so far. I can read the binary file and parse its contents row by row in a Float64Array.

But for some reason it seems slower than reading a csv (text) file, splitting it by line, splitting it by comma, do parseFloat over the cells.

Am I not seeing the bigger picture of binary, buffers and TypedArrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bottleneck is `new Float64Array` for each (small) chunk.

You could use 3 Float64 parameters instead, or work directly on the chunk.

Or use `Float64Array` on a much larger chunk, and call the function repeatedly using the same `Float64Array`.

Comment: Indeed. I increased the chunk size, made a buffer for it and it went a lot better already. Pretty dumb, cause I was reading 24 bytes at a time, calling a Float64Array constructor with all 'background' processing included, and expected good result.. 750.000 per second was still fast if you think of it.. Now reaching almost 10.000.000 p/s :) Thanks